# Is there a date-formatting bug in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

[image: Weird~]

This is what I've encountered recently
Whenever I type 10/13 on A79 It pops out Oct-14 to me.(But other columns worked normally)

These are the maximum details I can give, and please point out where should I elaborate more if the question is unclear.
Well, is this a bug?

Comment: what about A81 for example? check the number format in A81 and A79 and see the difference.

Comment: A81 works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format for the cell in question is differnt from the other date cells in column A.  I suspect you are displaying Mmm-YY.  Please right click the cell and correct its date format.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the problem! Found it and changed back to d-mmm~ In the forehand, why does it change? (I didn't do anything)

Comment: No idea how it changed, perhaps a paste. If you only wish to paste a value (and not the formats too) you must use `paste special | values only` Please feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I typed them all myself(no pasting occurs in the whole excel). So maybe(just joking) Microsoft isn't happy with that I'm still using Office 07 and not their latest products~ Btw gonna accept after the 10 minutes border.